# Trouble Getting a Locally Hosted Copy of the English Language Wiktionary to include the Translations Sections

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I used MWDumper - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Mwdumper - to import the xml dump of the English Language Wiktionary (specifically the file named enwiktionary-20120930-pages-meta-current.xml,) to my local server.

I have found that under the Translations section (on each page for each English word,) next to the name of each language where I should be able to see the definition in a foreign language, I instead see *Template:Tø*, *Template:T+*, or *Template:T-* and I am not sure why this is.

As an experiment, I also used WikiTaxi - http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/wikitaxi/index - with the exact same XML dump and did not have this problem when viewing under WikiTaxi.exe.

I have been searching through [mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) looking for the answer, but have so far not been successful.

Comment: Did you import all namespaces, including `Template`? If you did, your local copy should for example contain the page `Template:T+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out that MWDumper did the right thing importing the xml dump. All the translations are there. I just had to click on the *Template:T+*, *Template:T-* and *Template:Tø* links and add a template according to the instructions at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Templates.